# How to re-sync Gemfile.lock on changes to Gemfile

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rvm, bundler

How to re-sync Gemfile.lock on changes to Gemfile.

Assuming I have 3 gems (gem1, gem2, gem3) in the Gemfile.

`bundle install` creates a Gemfile.lock file.

If I remove gem3 and run `bundle install`, I would like Gemfile.lock to be re-generated and gem3 removed from the rvm gemset. But it doesn't, how should I re-sync without dropping the gemset.

Comment: It says the Gemfile's dependencies are satisfied. But I don't want any references to gem3 in Gemfile.lock.

Comment: `bundle check` also recreates `Gemfile.lock`. Isn't it what you want?

Comment: Good, but didn't `bundle install` do the same job for you? You probably also had neglected to run `git diff` (or to check your `Gemfile.lock` visually) to make sure your `Gemfile.lock` had been changed.

Comment: You are right bundle install does it too, didn't do a git diff. But I guess my real question, how would I remove it from the rvm gemset on a any removal.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

To bring the Gemfile.lock in line with Gemfile edits, run `bundle check`.

To bring the Gemfile.lock in line with both the Gemfile edits AND the latest compatible gems, run `bundle update`.

---

Related: This blogpost by viget has some good advice on [Bundler Best Practices](http://viget.com/extend/bundler-best-practices)

Comment: bundle update will overide the gem version you specivied into your Gemfile

Comment: This shouldn't have been marked as the answer, as it updates all of your gems to their most recent versions, which isn't what you wanted to do. To any visitors: look in the comments for the question to see the real answer (bundle install).