# How to ensure that the RVM gemset is also in sync when there are changes to Gemfile

Tags: ruby-on-rails

[How to re-sync Gemfile.lock on changes to Gemfile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13101945/how-to-re-sync-gemfile-lock-on-changes-to-gemfile)

This issue is a continuation to the above question, my RVM gemset is not in sync even when changes have been made to the Gemfile.

i.e. If I migrate a gem from version 1.0 to 2.0, both of them exist. I would want the previous gem 1.0 to be removed from my gemset in such cases.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're sharing gemsets between apps, this functionality would potentially break your other apps that rely on different gems. This is why I don't bother with gemsets anymore.

Disk space is cheap, if you're really concerned you can just clear out your gems periodically and then re-bundle to reinstall only whats in your bundle.

Comment: I am not sharing between apps, but I don't want an older version of the gem sitting in my gemset

Comment: How do I know, which version of the gem is picked up by the application.

Comment: The one in your Gemfile.lock. That is its purpose.

Answer (score 1):

You can do "gem cleanup" to remove old versions of installed gems in the local repository